pasar datos del formulario secundario al formulario principal datagridview c#
Tengo dos formulario padre e hijo, en el formulario padre hay una datagridview con nombre "" y el botones Multiseleccion que permite acceder al formulario hijo


            using (var Iform = new mdProductos())
            {
                var result = Iform.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    foreach (var producto1 in lista)
                    {
                        dgvdata.Rows.Add(producto1.IdProducto, producto1.Codigo, producto1.Producto, producto1.Categoria, producto1.Medida, producto1.Cantidad);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    txtcodproducto.Select();
                }




al hacer click en el noton multiseleccion carga el formulario secundario que tiene dos datagridview con nombres dgvdata y dgvdataselec

en el formulario hijo del boton registrar y cerrar se tiene el siguiente codigo:


private void btnRegistroCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   
               

    foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dgvdataSelec.Rows)
    {
        Producto1 dt = new Producto1();
        {
            dt.IdProducto = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
            dt.Codigo = fila.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Producto = fila.Cells["Producto"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Categoria = fila.Cells["Categoria"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Medida = fila.Cells["Medida"].Value.ToString();
            dt.Cantidad = fila.Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString();
            dt.PrecioVenta = fila.Cells["Precio"].Value.ToString();
        };
    }

    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    dgvdataSelec.DataSource = null;
    this.Close();



el problema que tengo es que no logro pasar la lista del formulatio secundario a la principal

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y porque es que no lo logras??? que intentaste?? porque esto es simplemente devolver algo a algun metodo, tener un objeto compartido entre los dos... hay varias formas... programar con formularios es lo mismo que programar con objetos (un formulario es un objeto) con lo cual, la teoria es la misma, si tuvieras un objeto al lado de otro, como comparten info???
